# AWS Distribute HTTP request with Load Balancer

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-elb

Using AWS, I want to:

- Distribute `http request` sending over several different `IP`s
- Send this requests without using proxy
- Send this using `Elastic Load Balancer` and `AutoScaling Group`
- Send these requests from one instance to several instances in `AutoScaling Group`
- Each of those several instances assigns different IP to the incoming request so output the request in its IP

How do I do this? Is there anyway to set up load balancer just to send through `http request`? I want each `http` request to have different `IP` address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you're willing to connect to EC2 instances behind a ELB *and* willing to know, on the EC2 instances, the original IP address of the connection, not the ELB's IP address.

If my understanding of your question is correct, then the answer is

- Use TCP listener on the ELB, instead of HTTP listeners.
- Enable [Proxy Protocol](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-proxy-protocol.html) on the ELB
- on your EC2 instances, collect the original IP address

Full step by step and demo application is available on [AWS' blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-proxy-protocol/).